# Root Node design for a hierarchy/treeview in the user interface

Tags: c#, treeview, hierarchy, root-node

I want to display hierarchical data in the user interface in a treeview control.

The question is should the user has the freedom to define its first root node itself.

I do not care wether a tree has a root node to be a tree.

I just think about the advantage for the user having a pre-defined root node or not in the UI.

Do you see any disadvantage for the usability or that the user could be restricted from

certain posibilities having a pre-defined root node?

In my opinion the root node has this disadvantage:

- its just a stupid placeholder for nothing, just there so the children are there...
- it can usually not be deleted, thus I have to do extra checks...
- I have to think about a creative name for the root node

Do not need:

```
MySuperRootNode
  11
  12
    21
    22
```

Totally fine should be:

```
1
  11
  12
2
  21
  22
```

Comment: MySuperRootNode seems rather unimportant in this instance.

Comment: This is what I meant. A pre-defined root node is superfluous. The user should be able to have multiple root nodes...

Comment: I'm not sure there is a question here.  Is there a problem getting setting up the tree without that super node?

Comment: No problem here. Yes there is a question. From ground up we learn a treeview has a root node etc... But does the user/user interface care ? Is it not better to let the user choose what he wants?

Comment: I think this question belongs on [ux.stackexchange.com](http://ux.stackexchange.com).

Comment: Can you move it there? ok I did :P thanks